# Was it a big mistake of JavaScript language inventor to use function instead of a shorter word?

Tags: javascript, programming-languages, coding-style, naming-conventions

It seems that it would be wise to use def, fn, or fun for function definitions similar to Ruby or other succinct languages.

Now that it's too late to change things due to potential compatibility issues, the whole world is forced to suffer using that wasteful long name 'function' everywhere in JavaScript code.

Comment: Can't change the past, so why worry about it?

Comment: I don't think it is a real problem...

Comment: Code Readability > Optimization

Comment: It would be nice if it were smaller/shorter but this doesn't materially effect the difficulty of developing software in JavaScript. Anonymous functions are a nice feature however bad the syntax is.

Comment: how much time could typing 5 or 6 extra characters take???

Comment: @Matthew on why worry about the past - because future mistakes can be avoided by acknowledging past mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I would call it a "big mistake." But I do occasionally wish for something shorter, though. I'd want to use a special syntax, something like `|a,b|{return a+b;}` or even better, `|a,b|{a+b}` if it could implicitly determine the `return` for short expressions.

Sigh...

On the other hand, so we don't go away from this question feeling depressed, isn't it AWESOME how we have great shorthands for object and array literals in javascript? So awesome it brought us JSON! If you ask me, the data structure shorthands are much more important anyway, so cheer up. ^_^

Answer (score 3):

"Big mistake"?  Apparently not - JavaScript's more popular than Ruby or other succinct languages.  The two don't appear to be correlated.

There are lots of things to lament about JavaScript, but "function" isn't high on the list.

Answer (score 2):

```
function reply() {alert("No, it wasn't!");}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since functions are first class objects "function" seems like a good choice.